# More than 2 groupingBy operations in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

This is my "revenue_data.csv" file:

```
Client  ReportDate  Revenue
C1      2019-1-7    12
C2      2019-1-7    34
C1      2019-1-16   56
C2      2019-1-16   78
C3      2019-1-16   90
```

And my case class to read the file is:

```
package com.source.code;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class RevenueRecorder {

    private String clientCode;
    private LocalDate reportDate;
    private int revenue;


    public RevenueRecorder(String clientCode, LocalDate reportDate, int revenue) {
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
        this.reportDate = reportDate;
        this.revenue = revenue;
    }

    public String getClientCode() {
        return clientCode;
    }

    public LocalDate getReportDate() {
        return reportDate;
    }

    public int getRevenue() {
        return revenue;
    }
}
```

I can read the file and group by ReportDate, sum(revenue) in the following manner:

```
import com.source.code.RevenueRecorder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;

public class RevenueRecorderMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
        List<RevenueRecorder> revenueRecords = new ArrayList<>();

        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src", "main", "resources",
                "data", "revenue_data.csv");

        Files.lines(path)
                .skip(1)
                .map(s -> s.split(","))
                .forEach(s ->
                {
                    String clientCode = s[0];
                    LocalDate reportDate = LocalDate.parse(s[1], formatter);
                    int revenue = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);

                    revenueRecords.add(new RevenueRecorder(clientCode, reportDate, revenue));

                });

        Map<LocalDate, Integer> reportDateRev = revenueRecords.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                        summingInt(RevenueRecorder::getRevenue)));
    }
}
```

My question is how can I group by ReportDate, count(clientCode) and sum(revenue) in Java 8, specifically:

- what collection to use instead of the Map
- how to groupby and collect in this case (and generally for more than 2 groupingBy's)

I'm trying:

```
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

        Map<LocalDate, Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairedReportDateRev = revenueRecords.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                        new ImmutablePair(summingInt(RevenueRecorder::getRevenue),
                        groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getClientCode, Collectors.counting()))));
```

But getting the Intellij red-squiggle underneath RevenueRecorder::getReportDate with the hover-message 'Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context'.

Thanks

**EDIT**
For clarification, here's the corresponding SQL query that I'm trying to get at:

```
select 
    reportDate, count(distinct(clientCode)), sum(revenue)
from
    revenue_data_table
group by
    reportDate
```

Comment: Might be easier to create your own aggregate class and collect into that.

Comment: How do client codes like `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` map to an `Integer`? And how are multiple client codes supposed to be grouped into a single `Pair`?

Comment: Are you asking to combine groupBy `reportDate` to sum revenue as in `Map<LocalDate, Integer> reportDateMRR = revenueRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                        Collectors.summingInt(RevenueRecorder::getRevenue)));`
and groupBy `clientCode` to count as
        `Map<String, Long> getClientCode = revenueRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getClientCode,
                        Collectors.counting()));` in a single result?

Comment: `Map<LocalDate, Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairedReportDateMRR = revenueRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate, v -> new Pair<>(1, v.getRevenue()),
                        (p1, p2) -> new Pair<>(p1.getKey() + p2.getKey(), p1.getValue() + p2.getValue())));` I have not tested it.

Comment: @Holger: it's the count of client codes that'd map to an integer (hence, Collectors.counting()), so in my attempted example, the map would look like: {2019-1-7: <2, 46>, 2019-1-16: <3, 224>}

Comment: When you group by client key, you get a result containing client keys, i.e. a `Map` mapping from client key to a value, not an integer.

Comment: @Hadi: your solution works, only need to change the abstract Pair<>() with concrete implementations, thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your trying has not been successful, but I think is what you most want to express. So I just follow your code and fix it. Try this one!

```
Map<LocalDate, ImmutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Long>>> map = revenueRecords.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                    collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> new ImmutablePair(list.stream().collect(summingInt(RevenueRecorder::getRevenue)),
                                                                          list.stream().collect(groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getClientCode, Collectors.counting()))))));
```

And I borrowed some sample data code from @Lyashko Kirill to test my code, the result is below
[image]

This's my own idea, I hope I can help you. ╰(￣▽￣)╭

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as collectingAndThen() lead me to what I was trying to achieve (further clarified with an edit to OP) though it's slightly different from your actual code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you already use Java 12, there is a new collector `Collectors.teeing()` which allows to collect using two independent collectors, then merge their results using the supplied BiFunction. Every element passed to the resulting collector is processed by both downstream collectors, then their results are merged using the specified merge function into the final result. Therefor `Collectors.teeing()` may be a good fit since you want counting and summing.

```
Map<LocalDate, Result> pairedReportDateMRR = 
    revenueRecords.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                    Collectors.teeing(Collectors.counting(),
                            Collectors.summingInt(RevenueRecorder::getRevenue), Result::new)));
    System.out.println(pairedReportDateMRR); 

   //output: {2019-01-07={count=2, sum=46}, 2019-01-16={count=3, sum=224}}
```

For testing purposes I used the following simple static class

```
static class Result {
    private Long count;
    private Integer sum;
    public Result(Long count, Integer sum) {
        this.count = count;
        this.sum = sum;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "count=" + count + ", sum=" + sum + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Holger You're right, you can do it in a single collect. I have adapted my answer to your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: I’d reduce the indentation a bit, to avoid horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't produce map `Map<LocalDate, Pair<Integer, Integer>>` due to you want to do the second grouping, what means that for the same date you may have multiple Client Codes with separate counters per each of them.

So if I've got you right you wont to get something like this `Map<LocalDate, MutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>>`, if it's correct try this code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "C1,2019-1-7,12\n" +
            "C2,2019-1-7,34\n" +
            "C1,2019-1-16,56\n" +
            "C2,2019-1-16,78\n" +
            "C3,2019-1-16,90";

    Stream.of(data.split("\n")).forEach(System.out::println);

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
    List<RevenueRecorder> revenueRecords = Stream.of(data.split("\n")).map(line -> {
        String[] s = line.split(",");
        String clientCode = s[0];
        LocalDate reportDate = LocalDate.parse(s[1].trim(), formatter);
        int revenue = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);
        return new RevenueRecorder(clientCode, reportDate, revenue);
    }).collect(toList());

    Supplier<MutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>> supplier = () -> MutablePair.of(0, new HashMap<>());
    BiConsumer<MutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>, RevenueRecorder> accumulator = (pair, recorder) -> {
        pair.setLeft(pair.getLeft() + recorder.getRevenue());
        pair.getRight().merge(recorder.getClientCode(), 1, Integer::sum);
    };
    BinaryOperator<MutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>> combiner = (p1, p2) -> {
        p1.setLeft(p1.getLeft() + p2.getLeft());
        p2.getRight().forEach((key, val) -> p1.getRight().merge(key, val, Integer::sum));
        return p1;
    };

    Map<LocalDate, MutablePair<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>> pairedReportDateMRR = revenueRecords.stream()
            .collect(
                    groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getReportDate,
                            Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner))
            );

    System.out.println(pairedReportDateMRR);
}
```

Comment: re "... for the same date you may have multiple Client Codes ..." take a look at @Hadi's solution above. S/he uses a neat trick for solving key collision by using a BinaryOperator in addition to keyMapper and valueMapper. More details can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap), for e.g. thanks

Comment: Yes, but his/her solution counts all values, without grouping them by Client Codes like in this part of your example: `groupingBy(RevenueRecorder::getClientCode, Collectors.counting())`

Comment: @shanlodh if Hadi J’s code solves your problem, then the entire task description is wrong, as there is no relevance of the client code values and you’re not performing two grouping operations at all. Yet another case of “once you understood what you actually want, the solution is trivial”…